# breakpoint in a Objective-c program

Tags: ios, objective-c

I did this class method to print 'random names':

```
   +(instancetype)randomItem
{
    NSArray *randomAdjectivesList = @[@"Fluffy", @"Rusty", @"Shiny"];
    NSArray *randomNounList = @[@"Bear", @"Spork", @"Mac"];
    NSInteger adjectiveIndex = arc4random() % [randomAdjectivesList count];
    NSInteger nounIndex = arc4random() % [randomNounList count];
    NSString *randomName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@ ", [randomAdjectivesList objectAtIndex:adjectiveIndex], [randomNounList objectAtIndex:nounIndex]];
    int randomValue = arc4random() % 100;
    NSString *randomSerialNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c%c%c%c", 'O' + arc4random() % 10, 'A' + arc4random() % 26, '0' + arc4random() % 10, 'A' + arc4random() % 26, 'O' + arc4random() % 10];
    BNRItem *newItem = [[self alloc] initWithItemName:randomName valueInDollars:randomValue serialNumber:randomSerialNumber];
    return newItem;
}
```

here's the **main**:

```
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            BNRItem *item = [BNRItem randomItem];
            [items addObject:item];

        }
        for (BNRItem *item in items) {
            NSLog(@"%@", item);
        }

        items = nil;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i run the program, it stops in the class method here:

```
NSArray *randomNounList = @[@"Bear", @"Spork", @"Mac"];
```

I don't know what's wrong with that code.
Can you help me?

Comment: FYI - Instead of doing `arc4random() % x`, use `arc4random_uniform(x)`. It gives better results over time.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your method. Just remove all the break points, clean the solution and run again. It should not stop.

Even after doing it, program stops at that point then restart Xcode and try again.